# Why does coq's typechecker reject my map definition?

Tags: coq, type-theory

I try to experiment with list's definition.
For example let's see this definition:

```
Inductive list1 : Type -> Type := nil1 : forall (A : Type), list1 A
                               | cons1 : forall (A : Type), A -> list1 A -> list1 A.
```

You might think that the definition above is equivalent to this:

```
Inductive list0 (A : Type) : Type := nil0 : list0 A
                                   | cons0 : A -> list0 A -> list0 A.
```

Why this map:

```
Fixpoint map0 {A : Type} {B : Type} (f : A -> B) (xs : list0 A) : list0 B :=
  match xs with
    nil0 _ => nil0 B
  | cons0 _ v ys => cons0 B (f v) (map0 f ys)
  end.
```

accepted, but this one is not:

```
Fail Fixpoint map1 {A : Type} {B : Type} (f : A -> B) (xs : list1 A) :=
  match xs with
    nil1 _ => nil1 B
  | cons1 _ v ys => cons1 B (f v) (map1 f ys)
  end.
```

?

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a confusing aspect of datatype definitions. The problem is that `list1` is *not* equivalent to `list0`, because of how *indices* and *parameters* are treated in these definitions. In Coq jargon, an "index" means an argument declared to the right of the colon, as in `list1`.  A "parameter", by contrast, is an argument declared to the left of the colon, as `A` in `list0`.

When you use an index, the return type of `match` expressions must be generic with respect to the index. This can be seen in the type of `list1_rec`, a combinator for writing recursive definitions on lists:

```
Check list1_rec.

list1_rec
     : forall P : forall T : Type, list1 T -> Set,
       (forall A : Type, P A (nil1 A)) ->
       (forall (A : Type) (a : A) (l : list1 A), P A l -> P A (cons1 A a l)) ->
       forall (T : Type) (l : list1 T), P T l
```

This type says that given a generic type `P` indexed by lists and an element `l : list1 A`, you can produce a result of type `P A l` by telling Coq what to return on `nil1` and `cons1`.  However, the type of the `cons1` branch (the third argument of `list1`) says that the branch must work not only for the `A` that appears in the type of `l`, but also for all *other* types `A'`.  Compare this to the type of `list0_rec`:

```
Check list0_rec.
list0_rec
     : forall (A : Type) (P : list0 A -> Set),
       P (nil0 A) ->
       (forall (a : A) (l : list0 A), P l -> P (cons0 A a l)) ->
       forall l : list0 A, P l
```

The branch of `cons0` does not have the `forall A` bit, which means that the branch only has to work for the type `A` in `l : list0 A`.

This makes a difference when writing a function such as `map`. In `map0`, we are allowed to apply `f : A -> B` because we know that the argument of `cons0` has type `A`.  In `map1`, the argument of `cons1` has a different generic type `A'`, leading to this error message:

```
Fail Fixpoint map1 {A : Type} {B : Type} (f : A -> B) (xs : list1 A) :=
  match xs with
    nil1 A' => nil1 B
  | cons1 A' v ys => cons1 B (f v) (map1 f ys)
  end.

(* The term "v" has type "A'" while it is expected to have type "A". *)
```

Answer (score 0):

To be complete, you can define function `map` over `list1` :

```
Fixpoint map1 {A : Type} {B : Type} (f : A -> B) (xs : list1 A) :=
  match xs with
  | nil1 A' => fun _ => nil1 B
  | cons1 A' v ys => fun f => cons1 B (f v) (map1 f ys)
  end f.
```

This is an example of the so-called [convoy pattern](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/MoreDep.html). Usually, one needs to add a `return` clause to the `match` construct so that it typechecks, but here Coq is smart enough to infer it.

However, I certainly discourage using this definition of lists as it will be cumbersome to use in similar cases.